# Fill a shape with a pattern gradually changing in size in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, fill

[image: Fish body]

I want to create scales running horizontally across this shape such that they gradually reduced/increase in size towards the extremities laterally.

How would I best achieve this? Create a pattern swatch & then use the mesh tool to work it in to the shape or create a pattern brush? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A pattern fill with a mesh distortion is about your only option other than manually creating the variations.

[image]

**Shape -> Apply Pattern fill -> `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh` -> move the mesh points around.**

(Note best to do this on a *copy* of the original shape. That way you will still have the original without the mesh if needed.)

Comment: Hey Scott, could you please explain how to make this? I've used AI for a long time but I have no clue how to use a mesh to distort a pattern. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers buddy thanks for the nod. I thought as much. Have a great day.

Comment: I don't believe you @Vincent .. but I added an explanation.

Comment: You better believe me on this one, Scott . Before I read your answer, I never even knew it was possible!

Answer (score 0):

What about using a scaled-down version of your original shape and specify a few steps using the Blend Tool?
[image]

Comment: Nice off the page idea Franz worth investigating thanks for taking time to give me the idea. Enjoy the WE. G